# How do I open modal using bootstrap 4 by clicking a hyperlinked table cell and populate data in the model from SQL database using the clicked ID

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a page which displays data from SQL in a table and on that table one cell is hyperlinked and I want a modal (using bootstrap) to open and fetch data using the ID (the hyperlink value) and populate with data on the body in modal from SQL. I have tried different approaches but none is working well. The modal opens up but its not prominent as if its opening in background. Please help me with this.

Used Links in HEAD:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
while ($ticketdata = mysqli_fetch_array($ticketresults)) 
{
// Print out the contents of the entry
echo '<tbody>';
echo '<th scope="row"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ticketModal'.$ticketdata['ticketnumber'].'">'; 
echo $ticketdata['ticketnumber'];
echo '</a>';
echo '</th>';
echo '<td>' . $ticketdata['policynumber'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ticketdata['registration_number'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ticketdata['insuredname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ticketdata['contactnumber'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ticketdata['casestatus'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ticketnumber" value="'. $ticketdata['ticketnumber']. '">';
echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="deletedata" value="Delete">';
echo '</form>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tbody>';
}
?>
```

How do I pass the ID to the modal and where should I initialize the modal passing the ID (hyperlink) to populate the modal with data using the ID with PHP script?

[image]

Comment: what you show on modal ?

Comment: @KUMAR The table displays limited data but on model I want to display more details stored on that particular table from which the current table is fetching data.

Comment: ok for that you have to use ajax .

Comment: @KUMAR Anything with serves the purpose will suffice.

Comment: why you use use `<form>` method and <input type="hidden"> in your while loop?

Comment: @KUMAR I am using delete query for each row. That might not be the right approach.

Comment: try with my code, please. & let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<table>
<?php
while($ticketdata = mysqli_fetch_array($ticketresults)){
<tr>  
   <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $ticketdata['ticketnumber']; ?>" class="view_data" /><?php echo $ticketdata['ticketnumber']; ?></a></td>
 <td><?php echo $ticketdata['name']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $ticketdata['policynumber']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $ticketdata['registration_number']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $ticketdata['insuredname']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $ticketdata['contactnumber']; ?></td> 
 <td><?php echo $ticketdata['casestatus']; ?></td> 
 <td>DELETE</td> 
</tr>  
<?php } ?>  
</table>  
</body>  
</html>  


<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Policy Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

**Ajax Code:-**

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('.view_data').click(function(){  
           var ticket_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"select.php",  
                method:"post",  
                data:{ticket_id:ticket_id},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#detail').html(data);  
                     $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

**select.php:-**

```
<?php  
 if(isset($_POST["ticket_id"]))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '".$_POST["ticket_id"]."'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">';  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>S. No</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["ticketnumber"].'</td>  
                </tr>  

                <tr>  
                     <td width="30%"><label>Ticket Name</label></td>  
                     <td width="70%">'.$row["name"].' Year</td>  
                </tr>  
                ';  
      }  
      $output .= "</table></div>";  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: This is getting all the data required and I can fetch but the modal is not popping up. Please help

Comment: you have to add jquery.min.js

Comment: I had to put the jquery CDN first on the list,. Thanks a lot, mate :)

Comment: means your bootstrap modal in working with desired result?

Comment: Yes its working perfect. Now I need to fix a height for the modal box to fit all the data without scrolling.