# How do I use specific table row data in ajax post

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to click on my pay button so as to update payment to a particular company. Below is my UI
[image]

clicking on the **pay** button shows this
[image]

I would like to display the name of the company the payment is going to and also be able to update the payment on the **Total Remit** column as well as reduce the debt.

I have been stuck on this page for a long time. Below is my code so far:
**query**

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
try{

  $sql='select c.catid, c.`category`,
      ifnull(sum( s.`stock_in` * s.`stock_price` ),0) as `debt`, c.`remitted`
  from `tbl_category` c
      left outer join `tbl_stock_in` s on s.`category_name` = c.`category`
  group by c.`category` order by catid desc;';


  $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
  $stmt->execute();
  
}catch( PDOException $e ){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**code for table**

```
    <?php
    
    while( $rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
    
    echo'
    <tr>
    <td>'.$rs->catid.'</td>
    <td>'.$rs->category.'</td>
    <td>
      '.number_format($rs->debt,2).'
    </td>
    <td>'.number_format($rs->remitted,2).'</td>


    <td>
<button id='.$rs->catid.' class="btn btn-info btnremit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pay Company"></span></button>  
    
    </td>
    
    <td>
<a href="#.php?id='.$rs->catid.' class="btn btn-info" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Category"></span></a>   
    
    </td>
    
    <td>
<button id='.$rs->catid.' class="btn btn-danger btndelete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="Delete Category"></span></button>  
    
    </td>
     </tr>
     ';
    
}          
?>
```

**Here is my ajax**

```
<script>
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnremit').click(function() {
      //var tdh = $(this);
      var id = $(this).attr("id");

        swal("Enter Amount:", {
            buttons: true,
            closeModal: true,
            content: "input",
        })
        .then((amount) => {
            if (amount === "") {
                    swal("Oops!! You need to enter value.");
                return false
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: 'remit.php',
                    data:{rid: id, pay: amount,
                      <?php 
              echo  ' currentDate : "'.$savedate.'", //working
                      compnyName : "'#'", //how do i call the company name that is clicked
                      old_remit : "'#'",//how do i fetch the old remit from the table
                                  '
                      ?>
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                         swal(`Paid: ${amount}`);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        swal(`Error remitting: ${amount}`);
                    }
                });
            }
            
          
        });
    
        });
    });


</script>
```

**code for remit.php***

```
<?php
    
    #stock-in.php
    /*
        If you are using sessions you need to start a session!
    */
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    session_start();

    if( empty( $_SESSION['useremail'] ) OR empty( $_SESSION['role'] ) OR $_SESSION['role']=="Admin" ){
        exit( header('Location: index.php') );
    }

    /*
        Check that all fields that are required in the sql have been submitted
    */
    if( isset( 
            $_POST['rid'],
            $_POST['pay'],
            $_POST['currentDate'],
            $_POST['compnyName'],
            $_POST['old_remit']
        ) ){

        try{
            
            include_once 'connectdb.php';

            /*
                When inserting, updating multiple tables there is some sense in using a transaction
                so that if one part fails the db is not littered with orphan records
            */
            $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $pdo->beginTransaction();

            $remitID            =   $_POST['rid'];
            $new_remit          =   (double)$_POST['pay'];
            $current_date       =   $_POST['currentDate'];
            $company            =   $_POST['compnyName'];
            $old_rem            =   (double)$_POST['old_remit'];

            $paid               =   $new_remit +  $old_rem;

            /*
                The sql command should use placeholders rather than embedded variables - the names are arbitrary
            */
            $sql='INSERT INTO `tbl_category_remits` ( `payment_date`, `category`, `remitted` ) 
                VALUES 
            ( :pay_date, :comp, :remit, :price, :cost, :current_times )';
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
            $args=array(
                ':pay_date'        =>  $current_date,
                ':comp'            =>  $company,
                ':remit'           =>  $new_remit

            );
            if( !$stmt->execute( $args )  )echo 'stmt#1 failed';
            
            
            
            $sql='UPDATE `tbl_category` SET `remitted` =:payment WHERE `catid`=:rid';
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
            $args=array(
                ':payment'    =>  $paid,
                ':rid'      =>  $remitID
            );
            if( !$stmt->execute( $args ) )echo 'stmt#2 failed';
            
            
            
            /*
                If it all went well, commit these statements to the db
            */
            if( !$pdo->commit() )echo 'commit failed';
            
            
        
        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            /*
                Any problems, rollback the transaction and report issues - 
                not necessarily with the full `getMessage()` ~ perhaps just
                'Error!' etc
            */
            $pdo->rollBack();
            
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Please, how do I fetch the **company name and old remit** from the table when I click on pay. I need your help!!

Comment: in modal you want `company name and old remit`??

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. On the modal, I would like the company name to appear. I would also like to have both the company name and the old remit posted through ajax.

Comment: show your 'remit.php', code.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: see my this answer if it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468814/how-do-i-open-modal-using-bootstrap-4-by-clicking-a-hyperlinked-table-cell-and-p/62469690#62469690

Comment: I think clicking on the id would work for a specific table row. I have done that on confirm delete but the main issue here is to get the row data posted in my ajax, specifically the company name and old remit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226164/discussion-between-kumar-and-ugochukwu-anajemba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnremit').click(function() {
      //var tdh = $(this);
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
    })
})
```

You could use function where u can pass id,name etc.

```
function yourFunction(id,companyName,oldRemit){
    swal("Enter Amount:", {
        buttons: true,
        closeModal: true,
        content: "input",
    })
    .then((amount) => {
        if (amount === "") {
                swal("Oops!! You need to enter value.");
            return false
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', 
                url: 'remit.php',
                data:{
                    rid: id, 
                    pay: amount,
                    compnyName : companyName,
                    old_remit : oldRemit,
                  <?php 
                   echo 'currentDate : "'.$savedate.'"'
                  ?>
                },
                success: function(data){
                     swal(`Paid: ${amount}`);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    swal(`Error remitting: ${amount}`);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And from your html table row call this function like

```
<td>
<button onclick="yourFunction('.$rs->catid.','.$rs->category.','.$rs->remitted.')" id='.$rs->catid.' class="btn btn-info btnremit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pay Company"></span></button>  
    
</td>
```

Comment: how you echo `compnyName` , `old_remit` in modal.

Comment: You can set swal title as companyName. @KUMAR

Comment: Thanks for these efforts; I implemented it but got an error that says: Uncaught ReferenceError: Pinnacle is not defined.

Comment: Try this

<td>
<button onclick="yourFunction(\''.$rs->catid.'\',\''.$rs->category.'\',\''.$rs->remitted.'\')" id='.$rs->catid.' class="btn btn-info btnremit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:#ffffff" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pay Company"></span></button>  
    
</td>

Comment: It actually picked the name and all the data specified but failed to update the database with the value I entered.

Answer (score 0):

you can send country name and old remit from php as an object and by obj of jquery use them in correct element

Comment: Please how do I do that? I'm new to this.

Comment: in php you can return data with json_encode function like `json_encode(['name' => 'test' , 'remit' => 2])` then you can parse this response by jquery `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "test","remit":2 }' );` and set obj for element `("#countryName").html(obj.name)`. if it is input you can use `("#countryName").val(obj.name)`